# Jenkins console shows permission denied error when I run the test.sh file

Tags: linux, jenkins, permission-denied

I have created one .sh which contains java command required to run the tesng.XML file when I run this test.sh file on Jenkins it shows me permission denied error.

Jenkins console output:

```
Building in workspace /home/dev2/eclipse-workspace/weeklytask
[weeklytask] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins7439378074963422991.sh
+ ./test.sh
[TestNG] Running:
  /home/dev2/eclipse-workspace/weeklytask/enquiryreminder.xml

Starting ChromeDriver 2.40.565383 (76257d1ab79276b2d53ee976b2c3e3b9f335cde7) on port 8120
Only local connections are allowed.

FOLLOW UP REMINDER CRON WEEKLY CHECK TESTCASE FAILED 
PLEASE CHECK THE TIME INTERVAL SETTING 
SET THE TIME INTERVAL TO 600 
FOLLOW UP REMINDER CRON WEEKLY CHECK TESTCASE FAILED 
PLEASE CHECK THE TIME INTERVAL SETTING 
SET THE TIME INTERVAL TO 600 
[[Utils]] Error while writing to /home/dev2/eclipse-workspace/weeklytask/test-output/Suite/Test.html: /home/dev2/eclipse-workspace/weeklytask/test-output/Suite/Test.html (**Permission denied**)
[[Utils]] Error while writing to /home/dev2/eclipse-workspace/weeklytask/test-output/Suite/Test.xml: /home/dev2/eclipse-workspace/weeklytask/test-output/Suite/Test.xml (Permission denied)

===============================================
Suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

[[Utils]] Error while writing to test-output/junitreports/TEST-verify.enquiryremindertest.xml: test-output/junitreports/TEST-verify.enquiryremindertest.xml (Permission denied)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jenkins use the user `jenkins`. If you have created your file with other user, there might be permission issue on the file. To resolve change the permission on the files and allow other users to execute the script. You can use

```
chmod +x test.sh
```

The directory `eclipse-workspace` belongs to `dev2` user and here `jenkins` user is trying to write data in it. Give `jenkins` write permission on this folder. try

```
sudo chmod -R a+rw /home/dev2/eclipse-workspace
```

For more details about permission you can view [This tutorial](https://www.webhostinghero.com/blog/change-linux-file-permissions/)

Comment: I have  used the command given by u the shows following error 
                       
Building in workspace /home/dev2/eclipse-workspace/weeklytask
[weeklytask] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins5356816468432548580.sh
+ chmod +x maptest.sh
chmod: changing permissions of 'maptest.sh': Operation not permitted
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: You need to execute the command not in `jenkins`, but the in console where the file is located. The purpose of the above command is to change the executable permissions of the file by the user who has created the file. It will allow `jenkins` to execute the file then.

Comment: .sh file getting executed but showing permission denied error to others
check error 

Starting ChromeDriver 2.40.565383 (76257d1ab79276b2d53ee976b2c3e3b9f335cde7) on port 24072
Only local connections are allowed.

[[Utils]] Error while writing to /home/dev2/eclipse-workspace/weeklytask/test-output/Suite/Test.html: /home/dev2/eclipse-workspace/weeklytask/test-output/Suite/Test.html (Permission denied)
[[Utils]] Error while writing to /home/dev2/eclipse-workspace/weeklytask/test-output/Suite/Test.xml: /home/dev2/eclipse-workspace/weeklytask/test-output/Suite/Test.xml (Permission denied)

Comment: the directory `eclipse-workspace` belongs to `dev2` user and here `jenkins` user is trying to write data in it. Give `jenkins` write permission on this folder. try `sudo chmod -R a+rw /home/dev2/eclipse-workspace`. this will give write permissions to users on this folder.